# networkd status - wlp1s0: Could not join netdev: Operation not supported

Tags: networking, netplan, systemd-networkd

I'm struggling on using the wlan on a server 18.04.

this is my 01-netcfg.yaml:

```yaml
  network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
      dhcp4: yes
      optional: true
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: no
      optional: true
    enp4s0:
      dhcp4: no
      optional: true
    wifis:
    wlp1s0:
      optional: true
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      access-points:
          "SSID":
            password: "SSID_pwd"
  bridges:
    br0:
      optional: true
      - enp3s0
      - enp4s0
      - wlp1s0
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [10.11.12.1/24]
      routes:
        - to: 0.0.0.0
          via: 10.11.12.1
          metric: 100
      nameservers:
              addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
```

i use
`netplan generate` followed by `netplan apply`

There is no error in the configuration

This is the screen after networkctl and service systemd-networkd status

```
#networkctl
IDX LINK             TYPE               OPERATIONAL SETUP     
  1 lo               loopback           carrier     unmanaged 
  2 enp2s0           ether              routable    configured
  3 enp3s0           ether              no-carrier  configuring
  4 enp4s0           ether              no-carrier  configuring
  5 wlp1s0           wlan               no-carrier  failed    
  6 br0              ether              no-carrier  configuring


#service systemd-networkd status:
● systemd-networkd.service - Network Service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service; enabled-runtime; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2019-01-29 13:11:00 CET; 21min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-networkd.service(8)
 Main PID: 672 (systemd-network)
   Status: "Processing requests..."
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4642)
   CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-networkd.service
           └─672 /lib/systemd/systemd-networkd

Jan 29 13:11:00 3rdeye systemd-networkd[672]: enp2s0: IPv6 successfully enabled
Jan 29 13:11:00 3rdeye systemd-networkd[672]: wlp1s0: Could not join netdev: Operation not supported
Jan 29 13:11:00 3rdeye systemd-networkd[672]: wlp1s0: Failed
Jan 29 13:11:00 3rdeye systemd-networkd[672]: enp4s0: IPv6 successfully disabled
Jan 29 13:11:00 3rdeye systemd-networkd[672]: enp3s0: IPv6 successfully disabled
Jan 29 13:11:03 3rdeye systemd-networkd[672]: enp2s0: Gained carrier
Jan 29 13:11:05 3rdeye systemd-networkd[672]: enp2s0: Gained IPv6LL
Jan 29 13:11:06 3rdeye systemd-networkd[672]: enp2s0: DHCPv4 address 10.10.10.149/24 via 10.10.10.1
Jan 29 13:11:06 3rdeye systemd-networkd[672]: enp2s0: Configured
Jan 29 13:11:06 3rdeye systemd-networkd[672]: enp2s0: DHCPv6 address fdd1:f5cd:9b6a::a32/128 timeout preferred -1
```

SO far I haven't find any solution on how to let the wifi works nor find what it is wrong in interface setting

Please advise

Thanks

Comment: I don't believe that `optional: true` is a valid option for device wlp1s0 or br0. Any why would you bridge 2 ethernet devices with a wireless device? Also, try `sudo netplan -debug generate` to check your .yaml files.

Comment: The netplan return no problem from the .yawl. Everything works fine beside the Wlan. I will test if the boot hangs when I remove the option:true to any of the 2 interfaces.
I work on an Apu2c4 and I aim to create a cctv box with router characteristics

Comment: if I move the wlan outside the bridge with a static ip on networkctl the status of wlp1s0 change from failed to configuring but still no SSID transmitted...

Comment: wlp1s0 doesnt "transmit" its SSID... it's used to CONNECT to the specified wireless SSID/password. Also, .yaml files are VERY FUSSY about indentation and spacing. They may pass the `sudo netplan -debug generate` step and still fail. Go to https://netplan.io/examples and view the examples there... as your .yaml file had some spacing/indentation issues that might effect all of this.

Comment: See my partial answer. Try using it as a starting point and see how far you get. Report back to @heynnema

Comment: after @heynnema concern of his comment it took me a while to figure out that in my configuration the wlan settings were for connecting and not transmitting :(
Now I'll start to work on transmitting settings. Can we confirm hostap is the proper way?

Comment: I don't know how to turn your wlp1s0 into a hotspot. Why don't you try my .yaml file and see if everything else works? Your .yaml has too many errors to work properly. Report back to @heynnema

Answer (score 1):

Try this as a starting point. Adjust the static addresses for your specific environment.

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
      dhcp4: yes
      optional: true
    enp3s0:
      optional: true
    enp4s0:
      optional: true
  wifis:
    wlp1s0:
      access-points:
        "SSID":
        password: "SSID_pwd"
  bridges:
    br0:
      interfaces:
        - enp3s0
      addresses: [10.11.12.2/24]
      routes:
        - to: 0.0.0.0
          via: 10.11.12.1
          metric: 100
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
    br1:
      interfaces:
        - enp4s0
      addresses: [10.11.12.3/24]
      routes:
        - to: 0.0.0.0
          via: 10.11.12.1
          metric: 100
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
```